# Trigger tab click event via button

Tags: javascript, jquery, triggers

How can I trigger click on 2nd tab event via butto, with jquery?

[image]

```
$('#packingGrid2').trigger('click');
```

I tried do this with trigger pasted above, but it doesnt work. Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you sure your selector is correct?

Comment: Yes, console.log($('#packingGrid')); returns me "jQuery.fn.init {context: document, selector: "#packingGrid2"}"

Comment: Are you sure it's a click event you need to trigger? Assuming you're attempting to change the active tab, is there no method in the tab library you're using? Or other event to raise?

Comment: I mean I can go to 2nd tab through clicking on tab header and it works fine, but I dont know how to achieve the same result with clicking on button. I thought its a click event.

Comment: Try to manipulate CSS classes which make the selected tab "active"

Comment: It would be useful if you could provide the code for the tabs so that we can figure out where it could be going wrong

Answer (score 0):

@Keydose, there is my code.

```
        $items = [
                [
                    'url' => \Yii::$app->params['pjax_enabled']?null:Url::to(['step_1', 'tab' => 'packingGrid1']),
                    'label' => '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></i> Weryfikacja linii',
                    'content' => \Yii::$app->controller->renderPartial('step_1', [
                            'gridId' => 'packingGrid1',
                            'model' => $model,
                            'form' => $form,
                    ]),
                    'linkOptions' => [
                            'data-id' => 'packingGrid1',
                    ],
                ],
                [
                    'url' => \Yii::$app->params['pjax_enabled']?null:Url::to(['step_2', 'tab' => 'packingGrid2']),
                    'label' => '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i> Ustawienia pracowników',
                    'content' => ($model->isNewRecord) ? '<strong>Uzupełnij weryfikację linii</strong>' :
                    \Yii::$app->controller->renderPartial('step_2', [
                            'gridId' => 'packingGrid2',
                            'model' => $model,
                            'form' => $form,
                    ]),
                    'linkOptions' => [
                            'data-id' => 'packingGrid2',
                    ],
                    'active' => ($model->isNewRecord) ? false : true,
                ],
            ],
    ];
    echo TabsX::widget([
            'items' => $items,
            'position' => TabsX::POS_ABOVE,
            'encodeLabels'=>false,
            'bordered'=>true,
    ]);
```

Comment: I quit with TabsX widget. I have created my own tabs, where I have full control of them, topic is closed.